# Difference between foreach( if() ) and if( foreach() )

Tags: php, performance, standards

I have a piece of code that looks like this at the moment:

```
foreach ($array['subarray'] as $current) {

    if ($some_variable === 'some_string') {

        $new_array[] = $current['some_name'];

    } else {

        $new_array[] = $current['another_name'];

    }
}
```

The same code could also be written like this:

```
if ($some_variable === 'some_string') {

    foreach ($array['subarray'] as $current) {

        $new_array[] = $current['some_name'];

    }

} else {

    foreach ($array['subarray'] as $current) {

        $new_array[] = $current['another_name'];

    }
}
```

My question is; is there a real difference between the two or is it just down to preference? I'm mostly talking performance here, but also if there is some standard to how nesting is usually done in PHP.

Comment: just in first variant 1 `foreach` in second 2 `foreach` and for each `foreach` allocated memory.

Comment: Performance wise, the second is better (thought whether it's a noticeable difference depends on other factors). This is because in the first, you have the condition running on every iteration instead of the array, rather than once.

Comment: Why not use a function for those two loops in the second example?

Comment: I'm not really sure how a function would help in this example. Wouldn't that just add unneeded complexity? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4):

Considering those particular examples, the second example is better in performance (if condition used only once), but this approach would be even better:

```
$new_key = 'default_value';
if ($some_variable === 'some_string') {
    $new_key = 'special_value';
}

foreach ($array['subarray'] as $current) {
    $new_array[] = $current[$new_key];
}
```

**EDIT**

If the difference is not only the key name, then I would base the choice on complexity and similarity of code in `foreach`, taking DRY principle and code readibility into account first and micro optimization (usually not worth it) last. So, it depends heavily on what you are doing in those loops, how critical is your system and how big are your data structures.

Comment: Ahh, I see I was a bit unclear in my example. ´$current['default_value']´ varies with each iteration. A badly used example name on my part. But I still understand your point.